# moving images from subdirectories of a directory to a new directory with python

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

I want to move specific files (in this case image files) of subdirectories of a directory to a new directory.   I want to move images from`path/to/dir/subdirs` to `newpath/to/newdir`. every subdirectory of the source directory contains a lot of images.

the photo of the subdirectories is attached.
how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: any attempt at code?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes i have tries os.walk , os.listdir(os.path.join), shutil.move methods ,but they did not give me the desired solution  @ShawnRamirez

Comment: @Mo.be, you need to move only images skipping other files?

Comment: yes, i only need images in subdirectories. @OlvinRoght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to copy directory tree is to use [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree). To copy only images we can use `ignore` argument of this function.

Firstly let's declare source path, destination path and extension of files we want to copy:

```py
src_path = r"path/to/dir/subdirs"
dst_path = r"newpath/to/newdir"
ext_names = ".bmp", ".jpg", ".png"  # you can as much as you want
```

We need to pass to `ignore` a callable which will return list of files with different extensions.

It can be a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression:

```py
lambda _, files: [file for file in files if not file.endswith(ext_names)]
```

Or it can be a regular function:

```py
def ignore_files(_, files):  # first argument contains directory path we don't need
    return [file for file in files if not file.endswith(ext_names)]
# OR
def ignore_files(_, files):
    ignore_list = []
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(ext_names):
            ignore_files.append(file)
    return ignore_list
```

So, we just call `copytree()` and it does the job:

```py
from shutil import copytree
...
copytree(src_path, dst_path, ignore=lambda _, files: [file for file in files if not file.endswith(ext_names)])
# OR
copytree(src_path, dst_path, ignore=ignore_files)
```

Full code *(version with lambda)*:

```
from shutil import copytree

src_path = r"path/to/dir/subdirs"
dst_path = r"newpath/to/newdir"
ext_names = ".bmp", ".jpg", ".png"

copytree(src_path, dst_path, ignore=lambda _, files: [file for file in files if not file.endswith(ext_names)])
```

**Upd.**

If you need to move files, you can pass [`shutil.move()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to `copy_function` argument:

```py
from shutil import copytree, move
...
copytree(src_path, dst_path, ignore=lambda _, files: [file for file in files if not file.endswith(ext_names)], copy_function=move)
```